# DependsOn attribute in NUnit

Tags: nunit

Is there an equivalent to TestNG 'dependson attribute' in NUnit? Or are there any other means to mark dependencies in nunit tests?

Answer (score 2):

As I know, there is no such an attribute. you can use TestFixtureSetup/TearDown for preparation. BTW, every test case should be independent.